# Another quick SQL question

Tags: sql

I have the following table structure, A -< B represents one A can have many B

```
User -< Computer -< ComputerConfiguration -< Benchmark >- GameVersion >- Game
```

They are connected with PK int keys.

One user can have many computers, computer can have many configurations, configuration can have many benchmarks, and benchmark has FK to game version which has FK to game

How can I count a total number of unique games for each user?

Can I count number of computers, benchmarks and games per user - all in one query?

Comment: I believe it's best if you pause your development and study a bit of SQL. You won't be able to proceed much further like this if you need a database in your application.

Comment: No worries mate. I'm not a total noob :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be 100% specific on the answer we'd need to know which DBE you're using.

Please note this is just pseudo code, the general idea though would be...

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Game)
  FROM User
INNER JOIN Computer
  INNER JOIN ComputerConfig...
```

to answer your next question, if you want all of those counts in a single query you'll need to employ some sub-queries.

```
SELECT User, r1.ComputerCount, r2.BenchmarkCount
  FROM User
 INNER JOIN (SELECT User as UserId, count(*) FROM User INNER JOIN Computer ON (...) GROUP BY User) as r1 ON (User.id = r1.UserId)
 INNER JOIN (SELECT User as UserId, count(Distinct Benchmark) FROM ...) as r2 ON (User.id = r2.UserId)
```

... and so on

Comment: Thanks. It seems that sub-queries are not necessary, I can use multiple count(DISTINCT) when grouping by userid and it works fine.

Comment: Perfect!  Just out of curiosity, which database are you using?